Highly suspicious System.Map (5.14.21-150500.55.68) - Linux compromised?
I'm running the 5.14.21-150500.55.68 x86_64 kernel on OpenSuSe Leap 15.5. I have over 20 years of experience with many different distros, but I always come back to OpenSuSe for several reasons. I have knowledge about Assembler, C/C++ and Linux system administration, so I think I generally know about the topic which I want to address here.
I am aware that the System.Map is a list of the symbols (functions and variables) of the Kernel and that it doesn't tell anything about their usage by the running system. However, some of the entries and also their cumulative occurrence made me suspicious somehow. Here are some excerpts:
ffffffff81002020 t xen_hypercall_mmu_update
ffffffff81002040 t xen_hypercall_set_gdt
ffffffff81002060 t xen_hypercall_stack_switch
ffffffff81002080 t xen_hypercall_set_callbacks
ffffffff810020a0 t xen_hypercall_fpu_taskswitch
ffffffff810020c0 t xen_hypercall_sched_op_compat
ffffffff810020e0 t xen_hypercall_platform_op
ffffffff81002100 t xen_hypercall_set_debugreg
ffffffff81002120 t xen_hypercall_get_debugreg
ffffffff81002140 t xen_hypercall_update_descriptor
ffffffff81002180 t xen_hypercall_memory_op
ffffffff810021a0 t xen_hypercall_multicall
ffffffff810021c0 t xen_hypercall_update_va_mapping
ffffffff810021e0 t xen_hypercall_set_timer_op
ffffffff81002200 t xen_hypercall_event_channel_op_compat
ffffffff81002220 t xen_hypercall_xen_version
ffffffff81002240 t xen_hypercall_console_io
ffffffff81002260 t xen_hypercall_physdev_op_compat
ffffffff81002280 t xen_hypercall_grant_table_op
ffffffff810022a0 t xen_hypercall_vm_assist
ffffffff810022c0 t xen_hypercall_update_va_mapping_otherdomain
ffffffff810022e0 t xen_hypercall_iret
ffffffff81002300 t xen_hypercall_vcpu_op
ffffffff81002320 t xen_hypercall_set_segment_base
ffffffff81002340 t xen_hypercall_mmuext_op
ffffffff81002360 t xen_hypercall_xsm_op
ffffffff81002380 t xen_hypercall_nmi_op
ffffffff810023a0 t xen_hypercall_sched_op
ffffffff810023c0 t xen_hypercall_callback_op
ffffffff810023e0 t xen_hypercall_xenoprof_op
ffffffff81002400 t xen_hypercall_event_channel_op
ffffffff81002420 t xen_hypercall_physdev_op
ffffffff81002440 t xen_hypercall_hvm_op
ffffffff81002460 t xen_hypercall_sysctl
ffffffff81002480 t xen_hypercall_domctl
ffffffff810024a0 t xen_hypercall_kexec_op
ffffffff810024c0 t xen_hypercall_tmem_op
ffffffff810024e0 t xen_hypercall_xc_reserved_op
ffffffff81002500 t xen_hypercall_xenpmu_op
ffffffff81002520 t xen_hypercall_dm_op
ffffffff81002600 t xen_hypercall_mca
ffffffff81002620 t xen_hypercall_arch_1
ffffffff81002640 t xen_hypercall_arch_2
ffffffff81002660 t xen_hypercall_arch_3
ffffffff81002680 t xen_hypercall_arch_4
ffffffff810026a0 t xen_hypercall_arch_5
ffffffff810026c0 t xen_hypercall_arch_6
ffffffff810026e0 t xen_hypercall_arch_7

ffffffff819510c0 T inet_csk_clone_lock

ffffffff81912990 t tcf_proto_is_unlocked.part.53

ffffffff81a93cf0 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mc_batch
ffffffff81a93cf8 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mc_issue
ffffffff81a93d00 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mc_entry
ffffffff81a93d08 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mc_entry_alloc
ffffffff81a93d10 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mc_callback
ffffffff81a93d18 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mc_flush_reason
ffffffff81a93d20 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mc_flush
ffffffff81a93d28 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mc_extend_args
ffffffff81a93d30 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_set_pte
ffffffff81a93d38 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_set_pmd
ffffffff81a93d40 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_set_pud
ffffffff81a93d48 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_set_p4d
ffffffff81a93d50 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_ptep_modify_prot_start
ffffffff81a93d58 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_ptep_modify_prot_commit
ffffffff81a93d60 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_alloc_ptpage
ffffffff81a93d68 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_release_ptpage
ffffffff81a93d70 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_pgd_pin
ffffffff81a93d78 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_pgd_unpin
ffffffff81a93d80 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_flush_tlb_one_user
ffffffff81a93d88 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_flush_tlb_multi
ffffffff81a93d90 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_mmu_write_cr3
ffffffff81a93d98 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_cpu_write_ldt_entry
ffffffff81a93da0 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_cpu_write_idt_entry
ffffffff81a93da8 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_cpu_load_idt
ffffffff81a93db0 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_cpu_write_gdt_entry
ffffffff81a93db8 T __SCT__tp_func_xen_cpu_set_ldt
ffffffff81a93dc0 T __SCT__tp_func_hyperv_mmu_flush_tlb_multi
ffffffff81a93dc8 T __SCT__tp_func_hyperv_nested_flush_guest_mapping
ffffffff81a93dd0 T __SCT__tp_func_hyperv_nested_flush_guest_mapping_range
ffffffff81a93dd8 T __SCT__tp_func_hyperv_send_ipi_mask
ffffffff81a93de0 T __SCT__tp_func_hyperv_send_ipi_one
ffffffff81a93de8 T __SCT__tp_func_local_timer_entry
ffffffff81a93df0 T __SCT__tp_func_local_timer_exit
ffffffff81a93df8 T __SCT__tp_func_spurious_apic_entry
ffffffff81a93e00 T __SCT__tp_func_spurious_apic_exit
ffffffff81a93e08 T __SCT__tp_func_error_apic_entry
ffffffff81a93e10 T __SCT__tp_func_error_apic_exit
ffffffff81a93e18 T __SCT__tp_func_x86_platform_ipi_entry
ffffffff81a93e20 T __SCT__tp_func_x86_platform_ipi_exit
ffffffff81a93e28 T __SCT__tp_func_irq_work_entry
ffffffff81a93e30 T __SCT__tp_func_irq_work_exit
ffffffff81a93e38 T __SCT__tp_func_reschedule_entry
ffffffff81a93e40 T __SCT__tp_func_reschedule_exit
ffffffff81a93e48 T __SCT__tp_func_call_function_entry
ffffffff81a93e50 T __SCT__tp_func_call_function_exit

Here are some references:
xen_hypercall_set_trap_table
Worried coders finally wrote a Perl script to successfully hide suspicious functions like xen_hypercall_set_trap_table appearing in /kernel/notes
inet_csk_clone_lock
Red Hat vulnerability warning for inet_csk_clone_lock

The inet_csk_clone_lock function in net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c in the Linux kernel allows attackers to cause a denial of service (double free) or possibly have unspecified other impact by leveraging use of the accept system call. An unprivileged local user could use this flaw to induce kernel memory corruption on the system, leading to a crash.
Reported:   2017-05-15 13:25 UTC

Well, then as a last example I searched for the function tcf_proto_is_unlocked and besides some harmless looking implementation files, I also found it in a Bad trace (as child process of CTest). Interestingly enough this function was accompanied by many other dubious functions that are listed in my System.Map, actually you can find almost all of these functions whose names speak for themselves:
ffffffff81924140 T netlink_policy_dump_get_policy_idx
ffffffff81924190 t __netlink_policy_dump_write_attr
ffffffff81924630 T netlink_policy_dump_add_policy
ffffffff81924a00 T bpf_fentry_test1
ffffffff81928580 t ethtool_set_settings
ffffffff819396d0 t __nf_unregister_net_hook
ffffffff82296f08 r __ksymtab_nf_hook_entries_insert_raw
ffffffff822afc9c r __kstrtabns_ipv4_sk_redirect
ffffffff81941ab0 t inet_rtm_getroute
ffffffff819647b0 T tcp_send_rcvq
ffffffff819b44b0 t mrtsock_destruct
ffffffff81a945c0 T __SCT__tp_func_skip_task_reaping

I could make assumptions what this trace of "CTest" could say about the intention/purpose of "CTest", but I leave that up to you.
You can find some more excerpts of my System.Map on Pastebin.
Of course I searched for many more functions and in many cases the results strongly suggested that these functions are useful in the contexts of 1) gaining remote access to a Linux system, also by means of virtualization 2) hidden data transfer from/to the targeted machine 3) livepatching/tainting modules 4) obscuring traces of kernel modifications
I assume that this kernel modification is caused by corrupted firmware. When I checked my ACPI tables with FWTS it reports many fails and when I disassemble the dumped tables using iasl, it can't disassemble ssdt5 as there is something wrong with the code.
The reason for my assumption is that no matter which distro I install, the created System.Map will include all these suspicious symbols.
By the way, even my dmesg output looks suspicious when it comes to ACPI tables and some other things:
[    0.004697] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.004700] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000B5E28014 000024 (v02 HPQOEM)
[    0.004703] ACPI: XSDT 0x00000000B5E27728 0000F4 (v01 HPQOEM SLIC-MPC 01072009 AMI  01000013)
[    0.004708] ACPI: FACP 0x00000000B5E19000 000114 (v06 HPQOEM SLIC-MPC 01072009 HP   00010013)
[    0.004712] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000B5E06000 01219B (v02 HPQOEM 88C6     01072009 ACPI 20200717)
[    0.004715] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000B64CF000 000040
[    0.004717] ACPI: MSDM 0x00000000B5E26000 000055 (v03 HPQOEM SLIC-MPC 00000001 HP   00010013)
[    0.004720] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000B5E1E000 0072B0 (v02 HPQOEM 88C6     00000002 ACPI 04000000)
[    0.004723] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000B5E1A000 003A21 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 ACPI 20200717)
[    0.004725] ACPI: FIDT 0x00000000B5E05000 00009C (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     01072009 HP   00010013)
[    0.004728] ACPI: MCFG 0x00000000B5E04000 00003C (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     01072009 HP   00010013)
[    0.004730] ACPI: HPET 0x00000000B5E03000 000038 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     01072009 HP   00000005)
[    0.004733] ACPI: FPDT 0x00000000B5E02000 000044 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     01072009 HP   01000013)
[    0.004735] ACPI: VFCT 0x00000000B5DF4000 00D884 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 HP   31504F47)
[    0.004738] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000B5DF3000 000060 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 ACPI 20200717)
[    0.004740] ACPI: TPM2 0x00000000B5DF2000 00004C (v04 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 HP   00000000)
[    0.004743] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000B5DEE000 003E88 (v02 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 ACPI 00000001)
[    0.004745] ACPI: CRAT 0x00000000B5DED000 000BA8 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 HP   00000001)
[    0.004748] ACPI: CDIT 0x00000000B5DEC000 000029 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 HP   00000001)
[    0.004750] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000B5DEB000 000149 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 ACPI 20200717)
[    0.004753] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000B5DE9000 00148E (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 ACPI 20200717)
[    0.004755] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000B5DE7000 00151E (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 ACPI 20200717)
[    0.004758] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000B5DE6000 000641 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 ACPI 20200717)
[    0.004760] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000B5DE2000 00386E (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 ACPI 20200717)
[    0.004763] ACPI: WSMT 0x00000000B5DE1000 000028 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     01072009 HP   00010013)
[    0.004765] ACPI: APIC 0x00000000B5DE0000 0000DE (v04 HPQOEM 88C6     01072009 HP   00010013)
[    0.004768] ACPI: IVRS 0x00000000B5DDF000 0001A4 (v02 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 HP   00000000)
[    0.004770] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000B5DDE000 00008D (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 ACPI 20200717)
[    0.004773] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000B5DDD000 0008F0 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 ACPI 20200717)
[    0.004775] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000B5DDB000 001774 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 ACPI 20200717)
[    0.004778] ACPI: BGRT 0x00000000B5DDA000 000038 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     01072009 HP   00010013)
[    0.004780] ACPI: Reserving FACP table memory at [mem 0xb5e19000-0xb5e19113]
[    0.004781] ACPI: Reserving DSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5e06000-0xb5e1819a]
[    0.004782] ACPI: Reserving FACS table memory at [mem 0xb64cf000-0xb64cf03f]
[    0.004783] ACPI: Reserving MSDM table memory at [mem 0xb5e26000-0xb5e26054]
[    0.004784] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5e1e000-0xb5e252af]
[    0.004785] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5e1a000-0xb5e1da20]
[    0.004786] ACPI: Reserving FIDT table memory at [mem 0xb5e05000-0xb5e0509b]
[    0.004787] ACPI: Reserving MCFG table memory at [mem 0xb5e04000-0xb5e0403b]
[    0.004787] ACPI: Reserving HPET table memory at [mem 0xb5e03000-0xb5e03037]
[    0.004788] ACPI: Reserving FPDT table memory at [mem 0xb5e02000-0xb5e02043]
[    0.004789] ACPI: Reserving VFCT table memory at [mem 0xb5df4000-0xb5e01883]
[    0.004790] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5df3000-0xb5df305f]
[    0.004791] ACPI: Reserving TPM2 table memory at [mem 0xb5df2000-0xb5df204b]
[    0.004792] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5dee000-0xb5df1e87]
[    0.004792] ACPI: Reserving CRAT table memory at [mem 0xb5ded000-0xb5dedba7]
[    0.004793] ACPI: Reserving CDIT table memory at [mem 0xb5dec000-0xb5dec028]
[    0.004794] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5deb000-0xb5deb148]
[    0.004795] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5de9000-0xb5dea48d]
[    0.004796] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5de7000-0xb5de851d]
[    0.004797] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5de6000-0xb5de6640]
[    0.004798] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5de2000-0xb5de586d]
[    0.004798] ACPI: Reserving WSMT table memory at [mem 0xb5de1000-0xb5de1027]
[    0.004799] ACPI: Reserving APIC table memory at [mem 0xb5de0000-0xb5de00dd]
[    0.004800] ACPI: Reserving IVRS table memory at [mem 0xb5ddf000-0xb5ddf1a3]
[    0.004801] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5dde000-0xb5dde08c]
[    0.004802] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5ddd000-0xb5ddd8ef]
[    0.004803] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xb5ddb000-0xb5ddc773]
[    0.004803] ACPI: Reserving BGRT table memory at [mem 0xb5dda000-0xb5dda037]
[    0.004928] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.004930] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000021e2fffff]
[    0.004938] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x21e2d5000-0x21e2fffff]
[    0.005157] Zone ranges:
[    0.005157]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
[    0.005159]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
[    0.005160]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021e2fffff]
[    0.005162]   Device   empty
[    0.005163] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.005164] Early memory node ranges
[    0.005165]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009ffff]
[    0.005166]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009eeffff]
[    0.005167]   node   0: [mem 0x000000000a001000-0x000000000a1fffff]
[    0.005168]   node   0: [mem 0x000000000a20f000-0x00000000b5c65fff]
[    0.005169]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000bcffe000-0x00000000bdffffff]
[    0.005170]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021e2fffff]
[    0.005171] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000021e2fffff]
[    0.005175] On node 0, zone DMA: 1 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.005199] On node 0, zone DMA: 96 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.005415] On node 0, zone DMA32: 273 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.011322] On node 0, zone DMA32: 15 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.011631] On node 0, zone DMA32: 29592 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.012002] On node 0, zone Normal: 8192 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.012075] On node 0, zone Normal: 7424 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.012186] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x808
[    0.012193] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.012206] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 33, version 33, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
[    0.012211] IOAPIC[1]: apic_id 34, version 33, address 0xfec01000, GSI 24-55
[    0.012213] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.012215] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 low level)
[    0.012218] ACPI: Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.012220] ACPI: HPET id: 0x10228201 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.012229] e820: update [mem 0xb2bbe000-0xb2bd1fff] usable ==> reserved
[...]
[    0.012305] [mem 0xc0000000-0xefffffff] available for PCI devices
[    0.012306] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[...]
[    0.063807] APIC: Switch to symmetric I/O mode setup
[    0.064718] AMD-Vi: ivrs, add hid:AMDI0020, uid:\_SB.FUR0, rdevid:160
[    0.064720] AMD-Vi: ivrs, add hid:AMDI0020, uid:\_SB.FUR1, rdevid:160
[    0.064721] AMD-Vi: ivrs, add hid:AMDI0020, uid:\_SB.FUR2, rdevid:160
[    0.064722] AMD-Vi: ivrs, add hid:AMDI0020, uid:\_SB.FUR3, rdevid:160
[    0.064723] AMD-Vi: Using global IVHD EFR:0x206d73ef22254ade, EFR2:0x0
[    0.065001] Switched APIC routing to physical flat.
[    0.065605] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
[...]
[    0.249459] ACPI: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x0a200000-0x0a20efff] (61440 bytes)
[    0.249459] ACPI: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0xb5e29000-0xb751bfff] (24064000 bytes)
[...]
[    0.337996] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.SBRG.EC0._Q50], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-327)
[    0.338011] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-221)
[    0.338019] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.338557] ACPI: 13 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.341578] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.344714] ACPI: EC: EC started
[    0.344714] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[    0.345449] ACPI: EC: EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.345452] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.SBRG.EC0_: Boot DSDT EC used to handle transactions
[    0.345454] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.345471] ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.345472] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.345786] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.345787] PCI: Ignoring E820 reservations for host bridge windows
[    0.346307] ACPI: Enabled 4 GPEs in block 00 to 1F
[    0.351920] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [P0SA]
[    0.352033] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [P0SA]
[    0.359546] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [PRWL]
[    0.359583] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [PRWB]
[    0.359884] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [FN00]
[    0.360909] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
[    0.360915] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI EDR HPX-Type3]
[    0.361059] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform does not support [SHPCHotplug LTR DPC]
[    0.361323] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability]
[    0.361325] acpi PNP0A08:00: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
[    0.361338] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-7f] only partially covers this bridge
[...]
[    0.367225] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKA configured for IRQ 0
[    0.367300] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKB configured for IRQ 0
[    0.367368] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKC configured for IRQ 0
[    0.367450] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKD configured for IRQ 0
[    0.367523] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKE configured for IRQ 0
[    0.367585] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKF configured for IRQ 0
[    0.367646] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKG configured for IRQ 0
[    0.367707] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKH configured for IRQ 0
[    0.372575] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[    0.372577] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[    0.372583] ACPI: EC: EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.372584] ACPI: EC: GPE=0x3
[    0.372586] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.SBRG.EC0_: Boot DSDT EC initialization complete
[    0.372588] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.SBRG.EC0_: EC: Used to handle transactions and events
[    0.372619] iommu: Default domain type: Passthrough 
[...]
[    0.844401] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P000: Found 3 idle states
[    0.844591] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P001: Found 3 idle states
[    0.844724] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P002: Found 3 idle states
[    0.844896] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P003: Found 3 idle states
[    0.845068] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P004: Found 3 idle states
[    0.845247] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P005: Found 3 idle states
[    0.845383] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P006: Found 3 idle states
[    0.845526] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P007: Found 3 idle states
[    0.845669] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P008: Found 3 idle states
[    0.845811] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P009: Found 3 idle states
[    0.846017] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P00A: Found 3 idle states
[    0.846192] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P00B: Found 3 idle states
[    0.846459] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.848244] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[...]
[    5.432971] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SBRG.EC0.Z009], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
[    5.432991] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.UBTC.M318 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-531)
[    5.433020] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.UBTC._DSM due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-531)
[    5.433037] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: ucsi_acpi_dsm: failed to evaluate _DSM 2
[    5.433099] ucsi_acpi: probe of USBC000:00 failed with error -5
[    5.498753] NET: Registered PF_QIPCRTR protocol family
[    5.638749] rtl8821ce 0000:01:00.0 wlan0: Current addr:  38 d5 7a a6 38 f9 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[    5.638755] rtl8821ce 0000:01:00.0 wlan0: Expected addr: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[...]
[ 2997.634531] ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
[ 2997.634558] ACPI: EC: EC started
[ 2997.634559] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[ 2997.634798] AMD-Vi: Virtual APIC enabled
[ 2997.634861] AMD-Vi: Virtual APIC enabled
[ 2997.634880] LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
[ 2997.635318] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 2997.635384] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 2997.635386] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
[ 2997.635531] microcode: CPU1: patch_level=0x08608107
[ 2997.637737] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P001: Found 3 idle states
[ 2997.638118] Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP always-on
[ 2997.638131] CPU1 is up
[ 2997.638180] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x2
[ 2997.638414] microcode: CPU2: patch_level=0x08608107
[ 2997.641292] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P002: Found 3 idle states
[ 2997.641639] CPU2 is up
[ 2997.641665] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[ 2997.641800] microcode: CPU3: patch_level=0x08608107
[ 2997.644019] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P003: Found 3 idle states
[ 2997.644551] CPU3 is up
[ 2997.644578] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x4
[ 2997.645088] microcode: CPU4: patch_level=0x08608107
[ 2997.647296] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P004: Found 3 idle states
[ 2997.647795] CPU4 is up
[ 2997.647820] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x5
[ 2997.647943] microcode: CPU5: patch_level=0x08608107
[ 2997.650190] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P005: Found 3 idle states
[ 2997.650862] CPU5 is up
[ 2997.650890] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x8
[ 2997.651179] microcode: CPU6: patch_level=0x08608107
[ 2997.653426] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P006: Found 3 idle states
[ 2997.654092] CPU6 is up
[ 2997.654118] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x9
[ 2997.654271] microcode: CPU7: patch_level=0x08608107
[ 2997.656485] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P007: Found 3 idle states
[ 2997.657290] CPU7 is up
[ 2997.657314] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0xa
[ 2997.657550] microcode: CPU8: patch_level=0x08608107
[ 2997.659805] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P008: Found 3 idle states
[ 2997.660662] CPU8 is up
[ 2997.660687] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0xb
[ 2997.660848] microcode: CPU9: patch_level=0x08608107
[ 2997.663082] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P009: Found 3 idle states
[ 2997.664092] CPU9 is up
[ 2997.664116] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0xc
[ 2997.664358] microcode: CPU10: patch_level=0x08608107
[ 2997.666582] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P00A: Found 3 idle states
[ 2997.667657] CPU10 is up
[ 2997.667681] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0xd
[ 2997.667848] microcode: CPU11: patch_level=0x08608107
[ 2997.670087] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.P00B: Found 3 idle states
[ 2997.671260] CPU11 is up
[ 2997.672378] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 2997.674787] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[ 2997.732713] ACPI: EC: event unblocked

By the way, it is interesting that the FACS tables doesn't have any signature. Oh and it has been updated more than 200 times already, as I could notice using a Windows tool.
So what are your thoughts about all this? Of course the System.Map is also filled with functions which one has seen many System.Maps before would consider to be totally normal, but what about all these suspicious entries?
And my assumption should be correct that the firmware is manipulated and corrupting any OS, then there is nothing I can do, I guess. The code in the ACPI tables gets executed by Linux, it doesn't matter if you disable the ACPI subsystem by any kernel boot parameters.
This is how it was intended by the people who designed this immeasurable brilliant concept of remotely patchable firmware which can then in turn 'patch' your OS so you can either dump this joke of HW or just accept 'getting patched'. Of course there is not even the slightest chance of setting up a secure system on modern x64 hardware, since 100% of it is affected by this regretful flaws of the described concept. Firmware will get executed and you will only fool yourself, if you resort to something like QubesOS or OpenBSD wrongly assuming that those are not affected by this.
I would really appreciate it, if someone could give me some tips on how to expose the details of a corrupted Linux. I already did a lot of Kernel debugging, which was interesting to some degree, but this also has its limitations.
I could install a new distro and set up some IDS as a first thing to do, but then the kernel is already corrupted and if it's sophisticated then I doubt that the IDS will report valuable results. And to give you one example: I installed the Volatility Framework, successfully dumped the volatile memory using LiME and then I wanted to perform some analysis, but 'surprisingly' that just didn't work, installed plugins could not be used etc. Analyzing spyware on an infected computer usually won't yield many useful results, at least if the spyware is highly sophisticated.
Edit:
Pastebin is limited to 512kb, therefore I had to limit the number of excerpts, but I was able to upload my full System.Map on PrivateBin.
Moreover I uploaded my disassembled ACPI tables there as well.
What totally surprised me in this context was the fact that for the first time I was able to disassemble all tables using iasl. Previously iasl always found errors in ssdt5 and therefore didn't dissamble it. After having disassembled all tables successfully, I couldn't think of any reason for this, so I deleted the DSL files and started another try. And now ssdt5 contained errors again:
Input file ssdt5.dat, Length 0x1774 (6004) bytes
ACPI: SSDT 0x0000000000000000 001774 (v01 HPQOEM 88C6     00000001 ACPI 20200717)
Pass 1 parse of [SSDT]
Firmware Error (ACPI): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.SBRG.EC0._Q50], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload-495)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-372)
Could not parse ACPI tables, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS

